# Check intersections before export using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, arcgis-10.8

I have a toolbox that intersect many shapefiles from many folders and subfolders. But are exported shapefiles that don't intersect with the polygon or "mask". So, the output files are like 'NULL'. I need export *only* shapefiles that *really* intersect. How I can write this in the following script?

```
import os
import arcpy

inter = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
input_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = input_folder

list_fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_folder):
    for dir in dirs:
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(root,dir)
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
            if fc.endswith('.shp'):
                rename_shp = "intersected_{}".format(fc)
                rename_excel = "calculated_{}.xls".format(os.path.splitext(fc)[0])
                newfile = os.path.join(output_folder, rename_shp)
                newtable = os.path.join(output_folder, rename_excel)

                arcpy.analysis.Intersect([fc, inter], newfile, "ALL", None, "INPUT")
                desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
                geometry = desc.shapeType
                if geometry == 'Polygon':
                    fieldName = "NEW_AREA"
                    expr = '!shape.area@hectares!'
                    arcpy.management.AddField(newfile, fieldName, "DOUBLE")
                    arcpy.CalculateField_management(newfile, fieldName, expr, 'PYTHON')
                    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(newfile, newtable)
```

Comment: Intersect into memory/feature Class and count features, copy if any, skip otherwise